# Executing Perl Script From Linux Box Using SSH Causing "The local device name is already in use"

Tags: windows, linux, perl, ssh, system-error

I have a Perl script which maps two drives, and then proceeds to copy files one of the drives to the other. The Perl script is located on a Windows box, but we are SSHing from a Linux box into the Windows box to execute the script. When I run the script directly from the Windows box, everything works without issue, the drives are mapped and the files are copied over successfully. When I attempt to execute the script from my Linux box via SSH, the script fails and I get the following output:

```
The local device name is already in use.

Error mapping source \\xxx.xxx.net\localdirectory
```

This error occurs when attempting to map the first drive, I don't know if it would fail on the second drive as well since it has not made it that far.

I have several other Perl scripts that are executed this same way (via ssh from Linux to Windows box) and they execute without issue, this is the only one that maps a drive though. This is the code I am using to execute the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -t -t user@server "cd /Path/to/Perl/Script; /cygdrive/C/Perl/bin/perl.exe Script.pl"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this in the future, we we're able to get it working. The issue was due to the SVCCopSSH being used for the CopSSH service on our Windows machine. We had to disable the CopSSH service, set the Log On as the network account we were using to SSH from Linux to Windows, and restart the service. This fixed all issues we were having.

Answer (score 1):

What user is your ssh daemon running as?  Presumably System.  That user doesn't have authority to map network drives, as far as I recall.  Can you not just do this on the Linux box directly using samba?

Comment: I am logging in with a system account, when I do a whoami once I'm ssh'd in, it shows the account as: svccopssh

For the purposes of what I'm doing, it would make my job much simpler if I could just use the already existing PERL scripts without having to alter them. To accomplish this, I am SSHing from my Linux box into the Windows machine they are currently hosted on and just executing them. I can have our admin check the svccopssh account to make sure it has the correct privileges to map the drive.